# Quiz Game using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, classes, tkinter

[image: GUI]I have made part of a quiz game and realize that if I continue down this route my code could get huge, is there a way to simplify my code or make it more efficient?
The first couple of lines of MathsQuestions.txt are:

> 1.Work out the value of 3 × 8? a)12, b)14, c)16, d)18,
> 2.Work out the value of 4 × 2? a) 6, b) 8, c)12, d)14,
> 3.Work out the value of 8 × 2? a) 6, b)12, c)14, d)16,

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *




class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(MainMenu)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class MainMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        global photo
        global photo2
        global photo3
        global photo4
        global photo5
        global photo6
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="MainMenu", font=('Verdana', 40, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=2)
        #Maths Picture/Button
        photo = PhotoImage(file = "MathsPicture.png")
        photoimage = photo.subsample(3,3)
        button = tk.Button(self, image = photo, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(MathsQ1), MathsScoreUpdate()])
        button.grid(row=1, column=1)
Mathsscore = 0
def MathsScoreUpdate(event=None):
    global Mathsscore
    Mathsscore += 5
x = open("MathsQuestions.txt", "r", errors = "ignore")
MathsQuestions = x.read()
MathsQ = MathsQuestions.split(",")
x.close()
#symbols
#r = row
#q = question
#a = answer
class MathsQ1(tk.Frame):
    global Mathsscore
    def __init__(self, master):
        a = 2
        r = 4
        q = 0
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q1/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[1] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(MathsQ2), MathsScoreUpdate()])
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MathsQ2))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")
        print(score)
        print("Physics Question 1")
class MathsQ2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 7
        r = 4
        q = 5
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q2/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[6] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(MathsQ3), MathsScoreUpdate()])
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MathsQ3))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")
        print(score)
class MathsQ3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 12
        r = 4
        q = 10
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q2/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[11] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(MathsQ4), MathsScoreUpdate()])
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MathsQ4))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")
        print(score)
class MathsQ4(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 17
        r = 4
        q = 15
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q2/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[16] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(MathsQ5), MathsScoreUpdate()])
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MathsQ5))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")
        print(score)
class MathsQ5(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 22
        r = 4
        q = 20
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q2/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[21] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(MathsQ6), MathsScoreUpdate()])
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MathsQ6))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")
        print(score)
class MathsQ6(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 27
        r = 4
        q = 25
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q2/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[26] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(MathsQ7), MathsScoreUpdate()])
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MathsQ7))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")
        print(score)
class MathsQ7(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 32
        r = 4
        q = 30
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q2/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[31] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(MathsQ8), MathsScoreUpdate()])
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MathsQ8))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")
        print(score)
class MathsQ8(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 37
        r = 4
        q = 35
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q2/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[36] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(MathsQ9), MathsScoreUpdate()])
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MathsQ9))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")
        print(score)
class MathsQ9(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 42
        r = 4
        q = 40
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q2/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[41] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(MathsQ10), MathsScoreUpdate()])
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MathsQ10))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")
        print(score)
class MathsQ10(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')
        a = 47
        r = 4
        q = 45
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:" , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Q2/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[46] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda:[master.switch_frame(MathsEnding), MathsScoreUpdate()])
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=MathsQ[a] , font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MathsEnding))
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column = 5, sticky="ne")
        print(score)
class MathsEnding(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='center')
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Congrats on completing the maths quiz, you can see you score below.\n You can either go back to the main menu or try the quiz again" , font=("Verdana", 15, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Go back to MainMenu" , font=("Verdana", 20, "bold"), height =1, width = 18, command=lambda:master.switch_frame(MainMenu))
        btn.grid(row=1, column=0)
        btn = tk.Button(self, text="Restart the Quiz" , font=("Verdana", 20, "bold"), height =1, width = 15, command=lambda:master.switch_frame(MathsQ1))
        btn.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=["Score", Mathsscore] , font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Comment: Why do you have all of the "..." at the end? If it's to circumvent restrictions on having more code than non-code, there's a reason for that restriction. This type of action goes against site policy.

Comment: Welcome to code review! I have edited your title so that it only states what your code does. Anything else belongs in the body. Find more in [ask]

Comment: Please provide us with an example of the first few lines of MathsQuestions.txt

Comment: @BryanOakley I believe this question is off-topic, since this is a "part" of his project which he hasn't finished yet

Comment: added the first couple of lines from MathsQuestions.txt

Comment: @WilliamG: in a technical forum, it's important to be accurate. Are you saying that the file only has a single very long line?

Comment: @AryanParekh: I don't think it's off topic. While the OP says it's "part of" a program, I think they mean it's a complete program, except that they want to add more questions.

Comment: There is a question and then four possible answers, my bad for not specifying. This is a complete program but I want to add more category but i don't know if there is a better way of doing it instead of having a new class per page

Comment: @WilliamG A screenshot of the GUI would solve all the doubts!

Comment: @AryanParekh I have added a picture of the GUI

Comment: (With question *1)*, how do you earn a score above 0?)

Comment: It would be quite useful to be able to run your app; as it stands all that repeated code is rather useless to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there are lots of ways to improve it! Let's begin with the small stuff and work our way up:

### Undefined "score"

Either define it and then print it everywhere if you want, or just remove it. I removed it below.

### General style

Have a look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a good start on Python code style. Use vertical spacing, separate comment text from the hash, no spaces in keyword arguments, name functions in snake case, that kind of stuff.

### Imports

Discard the ones you don't use, and generally try to avoid star imports, because that can lead to name clashes and confusion. Let's just use a single import:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

### The big payoff: *don't repeat yourself*

Keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). When you see similar code twice, think about ways to write it only once. If you see it three times, you should definitely try to do something about that. Ten times? Boy oh boy. Fight that CTRL+C/CTRL+V instinct.

By parameterising the frame creation as follows, we can *drastically* reduce the complexity of creating multiple question frames.

```
class Question(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, r, q, a, q_number, q_text, switch_to):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')

        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore, font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:", font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=f"Q{q_number}/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(
            self,
            text=q_text,
            font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"),
            height=1,
            width=15,
            command=lambda: [self.master.switch_frame(switch_to), maths_score_update()]
        )
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(
                self,
                text=MathsQ[a],
                font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"),
                height=1,
                width=15,
                command=lambda: self.master.switch_frame(switch_to)
            )
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="ne")
```

Now creating frames is as easy as 1-2-3.

```
class MathsQ1(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=0, a=2, q_number=1, q_text=MathsQ[1], switch_to=MathsQ2
        )
        print("Physics Question 1")


class MathsQ2(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=5, a=7, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[6], switch_to=MathsQ3
        )


class MathsQ3(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=10, a=12, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[11], switch_to=MathsQ4
        )


class MathsQ4(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=15, a=17, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[16], switch_to=MathsQ5
        )


class MathsQ5(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=20, a=22, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[21], switch_to=MathsQ6
        )


class MathsQ6(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=25, a=27, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[26], switch_to=MathsQ7
        )


class MathsQ7(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=30, a=32, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[31], switch_to=MathsQ8
        )


class MathsQ8(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=35, a=37, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[36], switch_to=MathsQ9
        )


class MathsQ9(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=40, a=42, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[41], switch_to=MathsQ10
        )


class MathsQ10(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=45, a=47, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[46], switch_to=MathsEnding
        )
```

This should pretty much achieve the exact same functionality, but as we can see the question number stays the same across most questions. You should probably have it running from 1 to 10. You should also be able to abstract it some more yourself, maybe by extracting the font styles or creating and placing labels, but this is a start. Indeed I think the `switch_to` argument is not needed if you just pass the correct question number and use it as an index. And looks like the indices to `MathsQ` and `q` and `a` have patterns (`q = 5i`, `a = 5i + 2`, `qt = 5i + 1`), so they could be just calculated instead of inputting them by hand.

Here's the final code dump just for completeness, but try changing the code yourself! Because the question and picture files were not provided, I can't promise this will run 100 %, but it should be ok at least with some debugging.

```
import tkinter as tk


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(MainMenu)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


class MainMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="MainMenu", font=('Verdana', 40, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=2)
        # Maths Picture/Button
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="MathsPicture.png")
        photoimage = photo.subsample(3, 3)
        button = tk.Button(
            self,
            image=photo,
            command=lambda: [master.switch_frame(MathsQ1), maths_score_update()]
        )
        button.grid(row=1, column=1)


Mathsscore = 0


def maths_score_update(event=None):
    global Mathsscore
    Mathsscore += 5


x = open("MathsQuestions.txt", "r", errors="ignore")
MathsQuestions = x.read()
MathsQ = MathsQuestions.split(",")
x.close()
# symbols
# r = row
# q = question
# a = answer


class Question(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, r, q, a, q_number, q_text, switch_to):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='n')

        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=Mathsscore, font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Score:", font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=f"Q{q_number}/10", font=('Verdana', 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=MathsQ[q], font=('Verdana', 20, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(
            self,
            text=q_text,
            font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"),
            height=1,
            width=15,
            command=lambda: [self.master.switch_frame(switch_to), maths_score_update()]
        )
        btn.grid(row=3, column=3)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = tk.Button(
                self,
                text=MathsQ[a],
                font=("Verdana", 35, "bold"),
                height=1,
                width=15,
                command=lambda: self.master.switch_frame(switch_to)
            )
            btn.grid(row=r, column=3)
            r = r + 1
            a = a + 1
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="Maths Category", font=("Verdana", 25))
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="ne")


class MathsQ1(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=0, a=2, q_number=1, q_text=MathsQ[1], switch_to=MathsQ2
        )
        print("Physics Question 1")


class MathsQ2(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=5, a=7, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[6], switch_to=MathsQ3
        )


class MathsQ3(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=10, a=12, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[11], switch_to=MathsQ4
        )


class MathsQ4(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=15, a=17, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[16], switch_to=MathsQ5
        )


class MathsQ5(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=20, a=22, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[21], switch_to=MathsQ6
        )


class MathsQ6(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=25, a=27, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[26], switch_to=MathsQ7
        )


class MathsQ7(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=30, a=32, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[31], switch_to=MathsQ8
        )


class MathsQ8(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=35, a=37, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[36], switch_to=MathsQ9
        )


class MathsQ9(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=40, a=42, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[41], switch_to=MathsQ10
        )


class MathsQ10(Question):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(
            master, r=4, q=45, a=47, q_number=2, q_text=MathsQ[46], switch_to=MathsEnding
        )


class MathsEnding(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(expand=True, anchor='center')
        lbl = tk.Label(
            self,
            text=(
                "Congrats on completing the maths quiz, you can see you score below."
                "\nYou can either go back to the main menu or try the quiz again"
            ),
            font=("Verdana", 15, "bold")
        )
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        btn = tk.Button(
            self,
            text="Go back to MainMenu",
            font=("Verdana", 20, "bold"),
            height=1, width=18,
            command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MainMenu)
        )
        btn.grid(row=1, column=0)
        btn = tk.Button(
            self,
            text="Restart the Quiz",
            font=("Verdana", 20, "bold"),
            height=1,
            width=15,
            command=lambda: master.switch_frame(MathsQ1)
        )
        btn.grid(row=1, column=1)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, text=["Score", Mathsscore], font=("Verdana", 30, "bold"))
        lbl.grid(row=2, column=0)
```